# Scanning an integer using %c and a character using %d: unexpected results

Tags: c++, c, printf, output, scanf

I am unable to give a proper reason for the following code's output. Can anybody help me.

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  char ch;
  scanf("%c",&i);
  scanf("%d",&ch);
  printf("%d\n%c",i,ch);
  return 0;
}
```

input output:

```
input: 
a
45
output:
0
-
```

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: A beautiful example of why you should _not_ use `scanf`.  You tell the function to write a `char`, and you pass the address of an `int`.  You tell the function to write an `int`, and you pass the address of a `char`.  Both are undefined behavior, so you can get anything (including a program crash).

Comment: "Here's code that I know is wrong - why is it acting wrong?"

Comment: @LuchianGrigore But you **know** it should work correctly, it really should!!!!one11

Comment: when i run gdb, after first scanf() the value of i was 97 but after second scanf  it changed the value to 0. i want to know what is the thing which is making those changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading an `int` into a `char`.  Assuming that `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char)`, this will result in `scanf` writing beyond the end of `ch` with undefined consequences.

You should use the `%i` format specifier for `int` arguments and the `%c` for `char` arguments

```
int main()
{
  int i;
  char ch;
  scanf("%c",&ch);
  scanf("%d",&i);
  printf("%d\n%c",i,ch);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i understand what u r saying but   
when i run gdb, after first scanf() the value of i was 97 but after second scanf it changed the value to 0. i want to know what is the thing which is making those changes

Comment: @abhishekiiit The second call to `scanf` results in `sizeof(int)` (likely >=4) bytes being written to the one byte `ch`.  This results in undefined behaviour.  Presumably in your case it is writing beyond the memory allocated for `ch` and onto memory for `i`, over-writing the byte which previously stored 97.

Answer (score 1):

Don't lie to `scanf` or `printf`. Nothing good ever comes out of it.

In this case, you are trying to stuff 4 bytes into the space of 1 - which obviously doesn't work, however much you squeeze. The fact that your program doesn't crash is purely luck.

Comment: i was just experimenting :P And i want to know what went wrong. I know it is wrong but i want to know how the value changed to 0 not something else. And why GDB showed correct value after first scanf and changed the value to 0 after second scanf.

Comment: Because you are writing outside of the size of the variable you gave `scanf`. It is taking the address of the variable, but not it's size - the size is derived from the "%d" or "%c".

Answer (score 0):

This is [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).You are trying to confuse compiler by telling that to pop and push something different what exactly it should in `printf` and `scanf` statement respectively.

Comment: when i run gdb, after first scanf() the value of i was 97 but after second scanf it changed the value to 0. i want to know what is the thing which is making those changes

Comment: as i said it is undefined, no one can say exactly what is happening there.Please go through the link i gave about undefined.

Comment: Please consider the word push and pop i used in my answer.It will surely throw some light on your question.